# How can I create a long int from a char buffer?

Tags: c, arrays, long-integer

I have a **char buffer** with 4 numbers, in binary:

```
buffer[0] = 00000000
buffer[1] = 00000000
buffer[2] = 00000000
buffer[3] = 00000001
```

I want to "fetch" the 4 bytes of the buffer and create a **long int**.

In this case, the long int variable would be:

```
test == 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

---

This is my code but I have the feeling that it is conceptually wrong:

```
int main() {
         unsigned char buffer [4];
         buffer[0] = 0;
         buffer[1] = 0;
         buffer[2] = 0;
         buffer[3] = 1;
         for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                 printf ("%d\n", buffer[i]);

         long int * addr = (long int *) &buffer[0];
         long int test = * addr;
         printf ("test = %li\n", test);
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
1
test = 140728915197952
```

---

I was trying to use *pointers* because I think it's the right way but I don't understand myself at all.

My machine is `LittleEndian` if can help.

Comment: there are a few ways to do this of course. if you just want use a pointer to the memory in the char array, then that pointer must be a point to a long int, not a pointer to an int as you have done.

Comment: Look at what I've done, I edited.

Comment: make a long int, set it to 1 and look at the memory to see what's different.

Comment: long int has 8 bytes, char has 1 byte, therefore you need and array of 8 chars.

Comment: As far as I know `long int` is composed of 4 bytes. `long long int` 8 bytes.

Comment: You need to load the character values one by one.  There is no guarantee it will be aligned properly to treat as a larger integer in memory.  Or you might be able to place the array in a union with an integer, but even then you would need to know if you were dealing with a big- vs. little-endian architecture (and I'm not sure what the C standard says about that).

Comment: `long int` has is at least 4 bytes in size, but it can be bigger, depends on implementation, in my compiler `long int` has 8 bytes, you should test it to find out `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long int));` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *left shift* with *bitwise or* in the loop, like this:

```
uint32_t l = 0;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    l<<=8;
    l|=buffer[i];
}
printf("l=%x\n",l);
```

Shift and Bitwise operations are typically very fast in all processors.

Suggestion: *int*, *long* may have different size. To ensure 32bit size, please use uint32_t instead.

Comment: Do you recommend any free guide to get better at bitwise operations?

Comment: @ArdentCoder Not sure but https://www.guru99.com/c-bitwise-operators.html may worth a look

Answer (score 2):

The code could be:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
// ...

uint32_t test = buffer[0] * 0x1000000u + buffer[1] * 0x10000u + buffer[2] * 0x100u + buffer[3];
printf("test = " PRIu32 "\n", test);
```

It would be a good idea to use a fixed width type for this scenario , because `unsigned long` might have different sizes on different platforms .